# Accessing a field in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

When I hit our API and produce an error, I get the following response:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "status": "400",
            "title": "Bad Request",
            "detail": "There is already a user attribute by the name \"Attr1\", please adjust."
        }
    ]
}
```

How would I reference the detail field?

I have tried body.errors[0].detail but it isn't giving me anything back.

I am trying to parse it back like this:

```
"response": {
    "errors": {
        "message": {
            "error": "[{{statusCode}}-{{body.errors[0].title}} - {{body.errors[0].detail}}]"
        }
    },
    "type": "json"
}
```

Comment: Post the code where you are trying to access it.

Comment: Are you sure that your object is actually an object and not a string? Which package, if any, are you using to handle the response?

Comment: I suspect you're referring to the wrong variable `body`.